# Eye blink detection when slightly moving/rotating photo

Tags: opencv

I implemented an eye blink detection solution using the research from this article:
http://www.iu.hio.no/~frodes/unitech10/011-Krolak/

I use a Haar eye classifier to identify the two eye regions, then using template matching on both eyes to detect blink state change. I also require that the face and eye regions remain fairly still. It works pretty well, except I occasionally get false positive on photos if I slightly move them (particularly rotate/scale). Does anyone have any suggestions to eliminate such cases? I don't want to make the stillness too strict, because it makes the live case unusable.

Comment: You can stabilize the vidoes/align consecutive frames using optical flow or local descriptors.

Would that work for you?

Comment: Thanks Gil. What I ended up doing is scaling the subsequent eye region images to match the size of the template, instead of cropping same size. It works much better. I also assume that if haarcascade_eye.xml finds an eye and then it doesn't, that means the user closed his eye. It seems to be a valid assumption in practice, except for the edge case of covering the eye on the photo which is tolerable in my application.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented with some success two cascades, one that detect open eyes and one that detect closed eyes.

You can use the face detector and restrict the search on the eyes region, then apply the "open eye" cascade. The good thing with that approach is that you can add slightly different poses and angles for the eyes on the training set. Worked really well for me.